# React Day-Picker on react stand alone React App --- error TypeError: f.default.instanceOf is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

[React Day-Picker Error**of TypeError: f.default.instanceOf is not a function**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLI1h.png)

Comment: try ```objectOf``` instead